# Read input within the command bound to a key in bash

Tags: bash

How can I read input within the command bound to a key?

I've tried:

```
bind -x '"\C-b":read x'
```

After Control-b hitted, bash hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind -x` isn't designed to run interactive commands; it should only be used to run commands that produce output, then exit back to the shell. Also, `read x` would be executed in a subshell invoked by `readline`, so whatever value you input to set `x` would be lost when the subshell exits.